# What is the purpose of cd ` (backtick)?

Tags: linux, bash

*The following behaves the same in Fedora and CentOS.*

```
cd mydirectory
```

works.

```
cd notadirectory
```

works (gets an error from Bash).

However,

```
cd `
```

gives me some sort of prompt:

```
>
```

Nothing I've thought to enter gives any response, it merely heads to the next line to prompt again. I simply use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit back to my `root@localhost`.

What is the purpose of this and what can one do with it?

Thanks!

Comment: See [What does ` (backquote/backtick) mean in commands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/what-does-backquote-backtick-mean-in-commands/27432)

Comment: So your question is more about the `>` than about the backtick, since that can also occur in other situations

Answer (score 124, accepted):

What you've typed is a [backtick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27432) - it is the start of an instruction to bash to evaluate what you type as a command. The `>` is displayed to indicate you are still entering the command on the next line.

If you close the backtick you'll find the whole command will run. E.g.

```
~$ cd `
> echo /var`
/var$
```

Comment: You can even nest them. For a somewhat realistic example: `cd \`dirname \\`which ls\\`\`` = cd to the directory where the "ls" binary is located. (i.e. `cd /bin` since it's `/bin/ls`) [edit: phew, escaping that markdown is HARD]

Comment: @MSalters You've perhaps stumbled upon the reason why modern bash prefers `$()` to `\`\``. Your example (plus the correct quoting) would become `cd "$(dirname "$(which ls)")"` which is much less insane.

Comment: @Muzer It's not just bash that prefers it, but [it's recommended in the POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_06_03) to use `$()` over backquotes.

Answer (score 59):

[JohnC's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1203272/35237) already explains the backtick. But what you are also wondering about is the `>` prompt. This a continuation prompt, and it is not only triggered by a backtick, but *always* when your shell clearly knows you're not done entering a command. The easiest example is putting an explicit line continuation `\` at the end of an input line (which helps splitting long input):

```bash
$ echo \
> hallo
```

Note that just like `PS1` controls the command prompt's look, you can also set `PS2` to change the continuation prompt, e.g.

```bash
$ export PS2="(cont.) "
$ echo \
(cont.) hallo
```

There are many reasons for the continuation to occur. A single backtick is incomplete, but you could also enter something like

```bash
ls -l `which cp`
```

in a single line (side-note: It's recommended to use `$(` and `)` instead, since the parentheses make it obvious where the expansion starts and ends, while single backticks make it more difficult to see where one's missing. And nesting...). Other possible reasons for a continuation prompt:

- a missing `done` after `while` or `for`
- a missing `fi` after an `if`
- a missing `esac` after `case`
- a missing closing parenthesis, e.g. in subshells `(cd $HOME; cat .bashrc)`
- a missing command after piping `|` as well as conditional execution `||` and `&&` (not `&` though, since that's just making the command running in background)
- a missing closing quote (`'` or `"`)

Curiously enough, a missing brace `}` after a variable expansion `${` also causes a continuation prompt, but will fail due to the inserted space:

```bash
$ echo ${
> PS2}
bash: ${
PS2}: bad substitution
```

Comment: And the same thing happens when using quotes :)

Comment: I already knew the answer to this question when I saw it in the sidebar but I wanted to give you an extra, albeit, imaginary +1 for a very nice in-depth answer.  This is the sort of content that makes the StackExchange sites awesome.  So... Thanks and keep being awesome.

Answer (score 4):

It means that your command is not complete yet. In fact, the character backtick, `` ` ``, is used to delimit an inline command.

Example:

```
cd /tmp # Go to /tmp
pwd # Prints the current working  directory
ls `pwd` # Lists the content of the current working directory
```

Answer (score 0):

The backtick starts/ends command substitution. The shell reads the command inside the backticks, interprets the results, and places those results into the command. E.g:. ls `which cp` results in the "which cp" being executed and the result of that command, i.e, /bin/cp will be used as the argument to the ls command. This behavior is, however, deprecated, in favor of the more explicit and readable $(cmd) command substitution.

When typing cd `  The shell is expecting a command to be executed to follow, and, to be close with a backtick.

In the case of the variable expansion using braces the shell presents the continuation prompt because those braces are lexically evaluated before the expansion is done.